# Rename the value of a file according to value of a cell inside a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api

Basically is I have a sheet which control de name of other files :

[image]

Inside "source sheet" I have the cells in column A, which I put new names and cells in columns B, which contains the ID of the files I want to rename :

[image]

What I want is : each time I edit the names cell in column A, the file which belong to the ID chage the name, I mean rename.

To do this, I am implementing a Script in Google App Script which is the following:

[image]

This is the code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var edited_range = e.range;
  var edited_row = edited_range.getRow();
  var newName = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,1).getValue();
  var idDeBox = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,2).getValue();
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idDeBox);
  file.rename(newName);
}
```

But It doesn't work. It doesn't rename the files. I am struggling with this.  What am I doing wrong ?

**Update :** I get this from execution logs :

[image]

Comment: It is a shared drive ? Any error message ?

Comment: @PuygrenierS. No error. Just does nothing. It's not a shared drive.

Comment: Please add the execution logs.

Comment: @Rubén. It dont have logs. Just say : Done. Dont have errors.

Comment: How are you running the function? Have you reviewied the Excution Logs page of your script project?

Comment: I update  to show the execution logs.

Comment: @Rubén. Cooper help me with the question. I really appreciate your help too.

Comment: Already answered -> [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/15954519)

Comment: @Ruben thank for your help. But that link is not even close to my question. But thanks. I really appreciate.

Comment: The link explains the error shown in the image and what could be done to avoid it

Comment: ahh ok. Even though it's strange because when running the function (in app script editor) make this error. But the function works perfectly editing. I'll read your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

Note: you are not actually specifying what cell you are actually editing.

```
function renameFile(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var newName = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
  var idDeBox = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).getValue();
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idDeBox);
  file.rename(newName);
}
```

and create an installable onEdit trigger with name of renameFile

Comment: Thanks , Thanks. I really apreciate your help. This WORKS. . . . OMG. There came a time when I thought about giving up. Thanks Cooper.  I never thought someone could help me with this.

Comment: Just One question. I dont really undestand when you say : ". . . and create an installable onEdit trigger with name of renamefile ". I did not do any of that. . . When I create the trigger ,  in the option: "choose which function to run" i put onEdit and in the option : "select even type" I put On edit. What do you mean with that ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to change the name of the function

Comment: ok. Now I understand it. One last question : why Do I have to exchance the name "onEdit" for "renameFile" . It affects something to have the name "onEdit" as function name ?

Comment: If you don't then your function will receive both the simple trigger and the installable trigger which can cause problems that are difficult to trouble shoot